# execute immediate sql command with single quotes not working

Tags: oracle

```sql
execute immediate 'create table AA_NEW  as 
select /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ * from AA 
where (to_date(time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) >= ((to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - 180 )';
commit;
```

- I am running this command within a plsql script along with other commands.

A new table AA_NEW is getting created. However, no records loaded in to new table.
It appears to be the time column has single quotes. So, I have tried with below.

```sql
execute immediate 'create table AA_NEW  as 
select /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ * from AA 
where (to_date(time, ''DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'')) >= ((to_date(sysdate, ''DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - 180 )';
commit;
```

No luck, data is not loaded. No records present in AA_NEW table.

Can some one please let me know what exactly is the syntax to be used so that, command runs successfully and data gets loaded in to new table.

Comment: `sysdate` is a date, so `to_date(sysdate)` does not make sense. If even the column is a date, you can simply remove all the `to_date` calls. Also, notice that a DDL (like `CREATE TABLE`) does not require a `commit`

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that the first statement, where the single-quotes were not expected, created a table AA_NEW but with no data in it - and the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement didn't throw an error? I don't believe that. And, if you give us inaccurate information, don't expect us to give you the best help possible.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping single quotes is a *must*; OK, you fixed that.

If no rows are inserted, then `WHERE` clause prevents them to.

- `sysdate` is a function that returns `DATE` datatype; you **do not** `TO_DATE` it
- what is `time` column's datatype?

  - if `DATE`, don't `TO_DATE` it
  - if `VARCHAR2`, use `TO_DATE`, but with appropriate format mask

Comment: select /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ * from AA
where (to_date(time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) >= ((to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - 180 );
-- above query results records 

select * from AA 
where time >= (sysdate-180); 
-- above query is not fetching any records, seems like, date column comparision is not correctly matching 

Is it like, time column and sysdate should have same date format ? If not, condition fails and no records fetched ?
Any setting to be modified ?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column time?

Comment: time is date column.

Comment: Then you dont need to convert it to date again in your query `time >= sysdate - 180` should work.

Answer (score 0):

- For string query, you can use quoted string. (`q'#....#'`) which will handle single quote nicely.
- Second issue with your code is `to_date` on already date column. (`Sysdate` and `time`)
- Third - just a suggestion. `Commit` is not needed.

In your table, I assume `time` is a date column then you dont even need to use the quotes.

You can use following code.

```
execute immediate 'create table AA_NEW as 
        select /*+ PARALLEL(16) */* from AA  where time >= sysdate - 180 ';
```